# Typescript: define a class type from the return of a function (and use it as a type)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, static-typing, typescript-class

Is there a way to define a class from the return of a function, and then use that as a property type in an interface?

```js
class Foo {};
function makeFoo<T extends Foo>(classType: T): T {
  return classType;
}
const Foo2 = makeFoo(Foo);
new Foo(); // OK
new Foo2(); // OK
interface IFoo {
  foo1: Foo; // OK
  foo2: Foo2; // 'Foo2' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.
}
```

The real world use case is I have a function that adds some static methods to classes using the class's generic types. So,

```js
class DataModel {}
class Foo<T extends DataModel> {}
class Bar extends Foo<DataModel> {
  getInstance() {
    return 'I am an instance';
  }
}

function addStatics<T extends DataModel, TF extends Foo<T>>(
  classType: TF,
): TF & { getStatic: () => T } {
  return Object.defineProperty(classType, 'getStatic', {
    value: () => {},
  });
}

// This is: typeof Bar & { getStatic: () => typeof DataModel; }
const BarWithStatics = addStatics(Bar);
console.log(BarWithStatics.getStatic(), new BarWithStatics().getInstance());
```

In reality it's doing some things with a singleton instance, but yeah, this is the gist of it. I was hoping there was some way to do `class BarWithStatics = addStatics(Bar)` but no such luck.

Answer (score 1):

Of course as soon as I ask this I figure out the solution. You can extend the return of a function:

```js
class BarWithStatics extends addStatics(Bar) {}
interface IFoo {
  bar: BarWithStatics;
}
```

Comment: You can also just change foo2: Foo2 to either foo2: typeof Foo2; OR even better foo2: Foo since makeFoo returns whatever it is given :) (in your first example i mean)

Comment: Using `typeof Foo2` doesn't work with the following error: `Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'Foo' but required in type 'typeof Foo'.ts(2741)`. And I didn't want to use `foo2: Foo` since I needed methods that would be defined on `Foo2`.